# AWS S3 static website hosting bucket end point is not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static, amazon-route53, website-hosting

I am trying to host my website using static website hosting in AWS S3.

In S3, I create a bucket  [www.example5.com](http://www.example5.com) and make it public.

```
Amazon S3 Buckets
Buckets (11) 

...
www.example5.com    US West (Oregon) us-west-2   Public
October 18, 2022, 14:56:52 (UTC+08:00) 
...
```

In AWS Route 53, I set up a hosted zone with the following 3 records :

```
Public example5.com

example5.com  NS  Simple  -  ns-175.awsdns-26.com.
                             ns-1882.awsdns-35.co.uk.
                             ns-579.awsdns-07.net.
                             ns-1163.awsdns-12.org.

example5.com  SOA  Simple  -    ns-175.awsdns-26.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

www.example5.com  A  Simple  -  s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
```

In S3 bucket [www.example5.com](http://www.example5.com), under the "Static website hosting" of "properties" tag, I define

```
Static website hosting

Static website hosting :  Enable
Hosting type : Host a static website 
Index document :  index.html (Specify the home or default page of the website.)
Error document :  index.html
```

In the bottom section "Static website hosting" of "Properties" tab of S3 bucket [www.example5.com](http://www.example5.com), I got

```
Static website hosting
Use this bucket to host a website or redirect requests. 

Static website hosting :     Enabled
Hosting type  :     Bucket hosting

Bucket website endpoint
http://www.example5.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Here comes the problems:

(1) When I click the above Bucket website endpoint on AWS S3 console,  I got this error in my browser

```
This site can’t be reached     
http’s server IP address could not be found.
...
```

and the url link in the browser address bar becomes a wrong url with '%20' in the end and extra 'http//' without colon in the front.

```
http://http//www.example5.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%20/
```

(2) When I type  "www.example5.com"  in browser address bar, I got the same error again

```
This site can’t be reached
http’s server IP address could not be found.
...
```

and the url in browser address bar changes to (again '%20' in the end, http// in the front)

```
http://http//www.example5.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%20/
```

(3) In browser address bar if I enter "www.example5.com/index.html" , I can access the webpage correctly. And browser address bar shows:

```
http://www.example5.com/index.html
```

(4) In browser address bar if I enter "www.example5.com/en/goal.html" , I can access the webpage correctly. And browser address bar shows:

```
http://www.example5.com/en/goal.html
```

Why I cannot use "www.example5.com" and why is the bucket end point not working ?

Comment: Did you specify `index.html` as the root object?

Comment: index.html is put in the root directory of S3 bucket www.example5.com. I do not quite understand what you mean "specify index.html as the root object".

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by deleting the S3 bucket and recreating it again.